How to use register contents with bang?
I am having trouble in using registers with bang. I am trying to make the following snippet to work:
vim9script

def WslYank()
  var text = shellescape(getreg('"'))
  exe $'!echo "{text}"'
enddef

WslYank()

but it does not work, I get e115 Missing single quote error. I am working with WSL2.

I believe you mean: exe '!echo $"{text}"' instead of exe $'!echo "{text}"'. At least with this one I can reproduce your bang problem.

Not really, I meant what I wrote. I want to use vim string interpolation for replacing {text} with the content of text but for some reason that I cannot capture why it does not work.

It's likely your unnamed register (") contains a string with a newline in it, or a similar special character that interferes with the quoting.
For example, take the following line of text:
test

If yanked into the unnamed register (via yy or similar), we can see that the output of shellescape(getreg('"')) has a newline in it:
:echo shellescape(getreg('"'))
'test
'

This newline at the end of the string causes the unmatched quote error you're encountering.
To avoid this you can surround the output of getreg('"') with trim():
:echo shellescape(trim(getreg('"')))
'test'

Note that this will also trim leading/trailing whitespace (tabs, spaces, etc), and not just newlines. To only remove newlines you can use trim(getreg('"'), "\n") -  see :help trim() for more details.
What is this snippet for? Might :help echo rather than !echo be more appropriate?

I took echo to be standing in for a more complex command relating to the clipboard on Windows
